# Where to write in viewcontroller using UITabBar

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I have 4 different viewcontroller and these are connect with 4 tabs in UITabBar. I have to write respected code in each viewcontroller but I noticed the code which is written in each viewcontroller is not loading. Where to write code in each viewcontroller when it is loaded after selecting tabs in uitabbar?

Comment: No it is directy added from IB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a view controller file for each view (simply right click on the left where the files are and do New File -> UiViewController).

After that, in the Storyboard, select the view, and in the properties, change from the default view controller to the custom one you have created (this is the third icon on the right panel, under "Custom Class"). The UITabBar should handle switching the views, and your code will make the views run uniquely :)